# How can I make Doctrine throw SQL errors?

Tags: php, doctrine

I can make PDO throw SQL syntax errors as `PDOException`s by passing an option in the PDO constructor or by using `PDO::setAttribute`. The object returned by `Doctrine::getConnection` looks and smells like a PDO instance, but it doesn't have the `setAttribute` method so I can't tell it to throw errors.

Any idea how I do that?

Comment: what gives you `var_dump($your_db);` ? Need this for further research

Comment: @hek2mgl: `object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)`

Comment: I don't expect that it extends PDO. It is just a wrapper (havn't seen code yet, will do).. What about the `$config` param in constructor?

Comment: @hek2mgl: I don't know anything about the constructor. I'm using the Symfony framework and it handles creation of service objects automatically (Doctrine being one of those services). I'm eyeing the ["driverOptions" configuration option](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options), but I can't figure out how to set it.

Comment: How do you instantiate the connection?

Comment: @hek2mgl: I don't - see my last comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29046/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-codemonkey)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the [driverOptions](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#custom-driver-options) option, which is equivalent to the `$driver_options` array passed to the [PDO constructor](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php). Either set it to:

```
array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)
```

or, when using Symfony, set the values of those constants in the Yaml config files:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        options: { 3: 2 }
```

Note that here the setting is called "options" instead of "driverOptions".